# purrr - extract rows of dataframe as vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataframe and wish to extract each row into a list
coerced as a vector. I want to use only `tidyverse` and `purrr`
packages to achieve this.

I have the following `reprex` where I tried to do this:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
# Create the raw dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(
    x = c("apple", "banana", "cherry"),
    pattern = c("p", "n", "h"),
    replacement = c("x", "f", "q"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# Define the function to extract the specific row index
# of the dataframe as a vector
get_row_vec <- function(df, row_idx){
    df %>% 
        dplyr::slice(row_idx) %>% 
        base::unlist() %>% 
        base::as.vector()
}

# Try and apply get_row_vec rowwise on the dataframe
# NOTE: This does not work! Need help to fix this
purrr::pmap(.l = df, ~get_row_vec(df  = .l, row_idx = 1))
#> Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent): object '.l' not found
```

Could anyone please help rectify the above code and please
help me understand how to do this with `purrr`?

EDIT: Per comments below, this is the ideal output I seek via `purrr`

```r
# MANUAL version of desired output
output <- list(get_row_vec(df, 1),
               get_row_vec(df, 2),
               get_row_vec(df, 3))
output
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "apple" "p"     "x"    
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "banana" "n"      "f"     
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "cherry" "h"      "q"
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't see the point of using `purrr::pmap` here; why not just e.g. `get_row_vec(df, 1)`?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I want every row extracted from the dataframe into a list. So it will be a list with 3 elements here. I'll clarify in the question details. I don't want to avoid a loop and use `purrr` functions to achieve this

Comment: In base R you could do `split(as.matrix(df), rownames(df)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `purrr::transpose` for this purpose:

```
library(purrr)
map(transpose(df), unlist, use.names = F)

#[[1]]
#[1] "apple" "p"     "x"    

#[[2]]
#[1] "banana" "n"      "f"     

#[[3]]
#[1] "cherry" "h"      "q"
```

Or if using `pmap`:

```
pmap(df, c, use.names = F)

#[[1]]
#[1] "apple" "p"     "x"    

#[[2]]
#[1] "banana" "n"      "f"     

#[[3]]
#[1] "cherry" "h"      "q"
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the rownames in the `transpose` or the `pmap`? In the `pmap` what is `c` a special operator?

Comment: both `unlist` and `c` accept `use.names` parameter, so if you don't need the names, you can set `use.names=FALSE`. `c` is the normal function in r to combine values as a vector. The same you use when you do `c(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
map(t(df) %>% as.data.frame(), ~unname(unlist(.x)))
#$V1
#[1] apple p     x
#Levels: apple p x
#
#$V2
#[1] banana n      f
#Levels: banana f n
#
#$V3
#[1] cherry h      q
#Levels: cherry h q
```

To avoid `factor`s

```
map(t(df) %>% as.data.frame(), ~unname(as.character(unlist(.x))))
#$V1
#[1] "apple" "p"     "x"
#
#$V2
#[1] "banana" "n"      "f"
#
#$V3
#[1] "cherry" "h"      "q"
```

Comment: this is coercing to factors which is not desirable but very much in the right direction

Comment: @user4687531 Please see my edit. Still not quite as clean/succinct as Psidom's answer.

Comment: Thanks Maurits Evers. I appreciate the help. I will also see if @Psidom can assist with some of my follow up comments. It is the likely way I will go forward

Answer (score 0):

fastest Base R:

```
as.list(data.frame(t(df),stringsAsFactors = F))
$X1
[1] "apple" "p"     "x"    

$X2
[1] "banana" "n"      "f"     

$X3
[1] "cherry" "h"      "q"
```

or you can do:

```
 split(unname(unlist(df)),c(row(df)))#split(unlist(df,use.names = F),c(row(df)))
$`1`
[1] "apple" "p"     "x"    

$`2`
[1] "banana" "n"      "f"     

$`3`
[1] "cherry" "h"      "q"
```